# Creating a list of used spot colors. Each textFrame colored with a corresponding spot color

Tags: javascript, adobe-illustrator

As in the title, I'm trying to create a list of all spot colors used in a document. Every name of a spot color should be in a different textFrame and each textFrame should be filled with corresponding spot.

I've tried to do it using swatches and i was semi-successful. It creates a list, but it's not coloring textFrames.

```
var swatches = doc.swatches;

if (swatches.length > 0) {

        for (var i = 0; i < swatches.length; i++) {
            var swatch = swatches[i]
            var color = swatch.color;

        if (color.typename == "SpotColor") {
            var swatchname = doc.textFrames.add();
            swatchname.contents = color.spot.name;
            var textColor = swatchname.textRange.characterAttributes.fillcolor;
            textColor = color;
        }
    }
}
```

I'm not sure why it's not working, even though the example below is working fine.

```
var docRef = app.activeDocument;
var myTextFrame = docRef.textFrames.add();
myTextFrame.position = [200,200];
myTextFrame.contents = "Hello World!"

var newCMYKColor = new CMYKColor();
newCMYKColor.cyan = 80;
newCMYKColor.magenta = 40;
newCMYKColor.yellow = 0;
newCMYKColor.black = 0;

myTextFrame.textRange.characterAttributes.fillColor = newCMYKColor;
```

Answer (score 0):

try changing:

```
var textColor = swatchname.textRange.characterAttributes.fillcolor;
textColor = color;
```

to:

```
swatchname.textRange.characterAttributes.fillcolor = color;
```

The first line in the code you posted is reading the value of fillcolor and saving it to the textColor var. The next line just updates the value of that var, rather than updating the fillColor attribute of the textFrame.